# Iterating manyToOne relationship in django executes hundreds of queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

There are **Users** who work on **Businesses**. **User** has a FK to the **Business** model.  In debug-toolbar it seems that normally all the **Business**.id are fetched in one query, but when I try to show the business name there are hundreds of queries executed (one for each **User**).

(*) I have removed all non-related raws from the code

**Users**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', blank=True, null=True, related_name="users")
```

**Business**

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class UserList(ListView):
queryset = Users.objects.annotate(num_assets=Count('assets', distinct=True),
                                  num_tickets=Count('tickets'),
                                  )
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UserList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

**template**

```
{% for user in object_list %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
         <td>
             {{ user.business }}
         </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is wrong and I am trying to run one query for them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). I am copying from the docs:

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

So your queryset should be something like this:

```
queryset = Users.objects.select_related('business ').annotate(num_assets=Count('assets',
      distinct=True),
      num_tickets=Count('tickets'),
 )
```

Comment: so easy? You are making me look like an idiot :) thanks!

Comment: @RobDel if Serafeim's answer helped you, consider marking it as correct